# Don't want a particular key and its value to show up in console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, debugging, console.log

So I am developing a expressJS app, in which I print all incoming requests and outgoing response of the app to the console.
Now I don't want some particular key and their values to show up on the console.
I use console.log() 
How can I skip those, some of them are nested within the object and not at the first level, otherwise it would have had been easy to do.
Or is there any other method of logging which allows blacklisting of deeply nested keys in the request and response objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify your object before logging. `JSON.stringify` method takes a function as a second parameter, in which you can specify what to actually stringify, so just emit the keys or values like so:

`const stringToLog = JSON.stringify(objectToLog, function(key, value) {
   if (key === 'dontWantThisKey) return;
   if (value === 'dontWantThisValue) return;
   return vlaue; 
});`